# T-SQL Delete duplicates leaving the one with max value from another table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, max

I'd like to ask you for a help in creating a query to remove the duplicates, but leaving the record with max value from another table.

I have a particular design of a SQL Server database.

Table **Main**:

```
|ID|  URL     | some other columns
+--+----------+
|1 |  URL1    |
|2 |  URL1    | 
|3 |  URL2    |
```

Table **Populars**:

```
|ID|  MainID  |UseCount | SearchString
+--+----------+---------+--------------
|1 |  3       | 124     | Phrase1
|2 |  2       | 234     | Phrase2
|3 |  1       | 123     | Phrase3
|4 |  1       | 7       | Phrase4
```

So in `Main` table I've got list of URLs where some of URLs are duplicated.
In `Populars` table I've got records with `UseCount` of each URL - there may be more than one record here for one URL, `where Main.ID = Populars.MainID`, but there may be also no related record in Populars for record in Main.

The problem is to remove duplicates from `Main` leaving the one which has the highest `UseCount` in `Populars`.

I tried multiple approaches, but didn't find the solution...

This query:

```
WITH ToDelete AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY URL ORDER BY id) 
    FROM 
        Main
)
DELETE FROM ToDelete 
WHERE RN > 1
```

removes duplicates properly, but leaves 'random' (from perspective of UseCount) record.

I have also an idea to create an additional column in the `Main` table, match all URLs in `Main` with `MAX(Usecount)` from `Populars` and insert this value into the new column and then try to remove duplicates. This would resolve the problem with multiple records in `Populars` related to each URL in main...

However I'm not very experienced in SQL queries...

At the very end orphan records (which have no related record in main) from `Populars` should be also removed.

I haven't found anything suitable for my problem - all similar questions are related to data in just one table - I'm struggling with it for few days trying to find a solution.

Do you have some ideas to reach the result?

Comment: What do you mean it "leaves 'random' record"?   It leaves the record with the lowest `id` for each `URL`.   There is nothing random about that.

Comment: It won't be random. it'll delete all rows other than the one with the lowest `ID`. You just need to change your `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause to be appropriate for what you want to delete. This sounds like you don't understand how the code you have here works; if so, that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: use `RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mainid ORDER BY id desc)` and see the result.

Comment: This is why I wrote 'random' in quotes - it's random from perspective of UseCount. And UseCount does not depend of ID anyhow.

This query:
RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mainid ORDER BY id desc)
Will not work just like that - MainID is a column in Populars table, when ID and RN are taken from main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,  I've found a solution.

I've created a view:

```
create view [dbo].[MainWithUseCount] 
as
select  *, (select max(usecount) as MaxUseCont from [dbo].[Populars] where MainID = ID) as MaxUseCount from Main 
GO
```

And after that, used:

```
        WITH ToDelete AS 
        (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY URL ORDER BY MaxUseCount DESC) 
         FROM MainWithUseCount)
 delete FROM ToDelete WHERE RN>1
```